# JSON and references to other JSON objects

Tags: json, powershell

I am new to powershell and trying to lean. I want to have parse JSON objects that have references to other JSON object in Powershell.

In my JSON file I define a default object with a value key=W.  I want to be able to use this $default.value reference in other JSON objects, to avoid having multiple places where a values are defined.

I cannot work out the syntax to be able to turn the string $default.value to the W value when I extract the key $driveletter=$json.target.driveletter

Is this possible in powershell?

Thanks

Stuart

Example.JSON

```
{default: {value: "W"},target: {driveletter: "'"$default.value"}}
```

doit-example.ps1

```
$json = (Get-Content "example.json" -Raw) | ConvertFrom-Json
#
#Create object called default that I can reference from other objects
#
$default=$json.default
$default.value
#
# How do I use the string in the json.target.driveletter 
#
$json.target.driveletter
$driveletter=$json.target.driveletter
$driveletter
$json.target.driveletter.GetType()
```

Output

```
.\doit-example.ps1
W
$default.value
$default.value

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     String                                   System.Object
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your json-file template to a string template that could be parsed more properly as a powershell-string template:

Example (test.json):

```
{default: {value: "W"},target: {driveletter: "$($default.value)"}}
```

Then you could do the following:

```
$file = "C:\tmp\test.json";
# Read the "template json with defaults"
$json = (Get-Content $file -Raw) | ConvertFrom-Json
# Read the raw content into a variable for expansion
$rawContent = (Get-Content $file -Raw);
# Set the default object (to be able to expand string)
$default = $json.default;
# Your new json
$newJson = ($ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString($rawContent)) | ConvertFrom-Json
```

This will replace the content of your "json" template with whatever default object you set. Note that you need to have the "default" set in your session when using expandstring.

The output of this example will produce :

```
default    target          
-------    ------          
@{value=W} @{driveletter=W}
```

You could access your propery for $newJson.targer.driveletter (and it will be set to your default)

To print your target driveletter (with the value(s) replaced from default) use:

```
$newJson.target.driveletter
```

Comment: Excellent.  Exactly what I was after.