# Merging JSON Objects at runtime in Powershell

Tags: json, powershell

Following on from a question yesterday ([JSON and references to other JSON objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35546990/json-and-references-to-other-json-objects)).

Is it possible to merge JSON objects at runtime in a similar fashion?

In my test.json I wish to insert the $Defaults.wimos object into WIMS.wimos at runtime similar to what I did for the $Paths.drive value in $Defaults.

```
{
    Paths: {drive: "W:"},
    Defaults: {wimos: {dstdrive: "$($Paths.drive)"}
    },
    WIMS: {
        winos: "$($Defaults.wimos)",
        wimre: {dstdrive: "$($Paths.drive)"}
    }
}
```

In the following code I cannot work out the syntax to have the object replaced at runtime.

```
$JSONConfig="test.json"
$rawJSON = (Get-Content $JSONConfig -Raw)
$pathJSON = $rawJSON | ConvertFrom-Json
#
# Load Paths from JSON into $Paths
#
$Paths=$pathJSON.Paths 
#
# Merge JSON objects to have the defaults replaced  
#
$DefaultsJSON=($ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString($rawJSON)) | ConvertFrom-Json
#
# Load Defaults into $Defaults
#
$Defaults=$DefaultsJSON.Defaults
#
# Merge JSON objects to have the System replaced  
#
$JSON = ($ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString($rawJSON)) | ConvertFrom-Json

$JSON.WIMS
write-host ("JSON.WIMS.wimre.dstdrive =" + $JSON.WIMS.wimre.dstdrive)
write-host ("JSON.WIMS.wimos.dstdrive =" + $JSON.WIMS.wimos.dstdrive)   #This fails to access and print "W:"
```

I would like to be able to replace $($Defaults.wimos) and be able to query the dstdrive member.

Is this possible to achieve this in powershell?  Any suggestions on how?

Thanks

Stuart

Comment: Version 5.0 Build 10240 Revision 16384 with Windows 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a couple of issues in your code. First, the value that would be inserted into your template would be interpolated as a string and not a json-object.

To do this, you could use the ConvertTo-json within the template. I'll show you how in a minute.

If you're gonna be recreating and using different "templates" within the same file (like path, defaults etc), I would create a helper function for recreating / filling out the template on your session variables all the time (in order to avoid repeating code).

Create the following method:

```
function Get-ParsedJsonTemplate(){
   return ($ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString((Get-Content $JSONConfig -Raw))) | ConvertFrom-Json
}
```

Change your template json to the following (showing you that you can use powershell code within your template file:

```
{
 Paths: {drive: "W:"},
 Defaults: {wimos: {dstdrive: "$($Paths.drive)"}},
 WIMS: {
    winos: $(
        if($Defaults -and $Defaults.wimos){
            $Defaults.wimos|ConvertTo-Json -Compress
        } else {
            @{"dstdrive"=""}|ConvertTo-Json -compress
        }
    ),
    wimre: {dstdrive: "$($Paths.drive)"}
 }
}
```

You also had a typo in either your template or your printout (I see that you used wimos in your "printout" in powershell and "winos" in your template. I modified the code and the following should work for you (given the above test.json):

```
$JSONConfig="c:\tmp\test.json"

function Get-ParsedJsonTemplate(){
    return ($ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString((Get-Content $JSONConfig -Raw))) | ConvertFrom-Json
}

$pathJSON = Get-ParsedJsonTemplate;
$Paths=$pathJSON.Paths 
$DefaultsJSON=Get-ParsedJsonTemplate;
$Defaults=$DefaultsJSON.Defaults
$JSON = Get-ParsedJsonTemplate;
$JSON.WIMS
write-host ("JSON.WIMS.wimre.dstdrive =" + $JSON.WIMS.wimre.dstdrive)
write-host ("JSON.WIMS.wimos.dstdrive =" + $JSON.WIMS.winos.dstdrive)
```

Comment: Excellent answer.  Thanks for the tip about powershell in JSON.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your script was failing was due to the fact that `$Defaults.wimos` was not the string `{ dstdrive: "W:" }` it was instead a PSCustomObject which would be interpolated to a the value `@{drive=W:}`.  To obtain the correct behavior, you need to convert the `$Defaults.wimos` value back to a json string.

```
$Defaults = $DefaultsJSON.Defaults
$Defaults.wimos = $Defaults.wimos | ConvertTo-Json -Compress
```